# Change dataframe column values based on condition using formula

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

| index | Team A | Team B | Site A | Site B | Odds A | Odds B | Profit % | Bet A | Bet B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 21 | Oklahoma City Thunder | Philadelphia 76ers | FanDuel | DraftKings | 2.26 | 2.35 | 13.2 | 195.79 | 181.08 |
| 23 | Oklahoma City Thunder | Philadelphia 76ers | FanDuel | BetMGM | 2.26 | 2.35 | 13.2 | 195.79 | 181.08 |
| 25 | Oklahoma City Thunder | Philadelphia 76ers | FanDuel | Caesars | 2.26 | 2.35 | 13.2 | 195.79 | 181.08 |
| 27 | Oklahoma City Thunder | Philadelphia 76ers | DraftKings | BetMGM | 2.35 | 2.35 | 14.89 | 181.08 | 181.08 |

The values in the Odds A and Odds B are decimal odds.  I want to change them to the American odds format using a formula.  If the value is greater that or equal to 2 then the formula is (Odds-1) * 100.  If it is less that 2 then the formula is -100/(Odds-1).

What is the best way to do that?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with your condition to assign the new values:

```
df['Odds A'] = np.where(df['Odds A'] < 2, 100/(df['Odds A']-1), 100*(df['Odds A']-1))
df['Odds B'] = np.where(df['Odds B'] < 2, 100/(df['Odds B']-1), 100*(df['Odds B']-1))
```

Comment: @Jerel Did this answer your question? If not, could you provide more information to help answer it?